# RISC-V startup code for stack pointer initalization

Tags: riscv

how to write a simple startup code in C which initialize the stack pointer for RISC-V processor? (which have to compile thorugh risc-v compiler)

thanks

Answer (score 5):

The simplest start code that sets up a stack looks something like

```
_start:
    /* Clear the link register, so debuggers know to terminate their
     * backtrace. */
    cfi_undefined (ra)

    /* Setup the global pointer, which the ABI assumes points to the
     * __global_pointer$ symbol. */
    .option push
    .option norelax
    la gp, __global_pointer$
    .option pop

    /* Setup the stack pointer.  This symbol will only be looked at
     * here, so you can pick any name you want. */
    la sp, __stack_pointer$

    /* Call main, leaving the arguments undefined. */
    call main

    /* Spin after main() returns. */
1:
    j 1b
```

you might also want to do something like calling `__libc_init_array` and registering `__libc_fini_array` with `atexit`, clearing `argc` and `argv` (a0 and a1 to main), relocating the data section, and zeroing the BSS, depending on exactly how much of the C ABI you want to support.

SiFive's Freedom E SDK contains our full startup code: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sifive/freedom-e-sdk/master/bsp/env/start.S , as well as the relevant linker scripts for some of our platforms.  You can also see more complicated in newlib (https://github.com/riscv/riscv-newlib/blob/riscv-newlib-2.5.0/libgloss/riscv/crt0.S) and glibc (https://github.com/riscv/riscv-glibc/blob/riscv-glibc-2.26/sysdeps/riscv/start.S), though those both assume that the stack has already been initialized by the execution environment.

Comment: I do not understand the concept of the cited crt0.S implementation. If we are talking about a bare metal system there is no _execution environment_ that could have set up the stack beforehand. `_start` is the entry point, there is nothing before that. And `_start` happily invokes `__libc_init_array` which **does** require a stack. Have I missed something?

Comment: @hermannk The answer does mention setting up stack and then doing what you want. So, _start sets up stack and only post that, it could invoke main/__libc_init_array. In the code snippet, you can replace the call to main with this and then call main.

Comment: ``la gp, __global_pointer$`` does not work for me. GCC optimizes it to ``mv gp, gp`` Any suggestions on how to correctly init the gp?

Comment: @GNA Nevermind. Solved it by using the norelax option like here: https://github.com/riscv/riscv-newlib/blob/riscv-newlib-2.5.0/libgloss/riscv/crt0.S#L10

Answer (score 2):

There is SCR1 - an open-source RISC-V compatible core
(https://github.com/syntacore/scr1) with SDK (https://github.com/syntacore/scr1-sdk, please, clone with submodules, recursively).

You can find sample applications in the SDK.

The startup code is located in the bootloader (https://github.com/syntacore/sc-bl).

See label `_crt_start` in src/startup.S:

- init CSRs
- clear .bss
- init stack
- init TLS
- boot
- call main