# __libc_init_array using stack pointer for writes before stack pointer is set

Tags: c, gcc, riscv, bare-metal, stack-pointer

The Problem: When I compile a C program for a bare metal RISC-V environment with GCC, the function `__libc_init_array` is using the stack pointer for writes to the memory before the stack pointer is set. The stack pointer is set in an assembly file that also initializes the registers.

The `__libc_init_array` function is not included in the created binary if the argument `-nostartfiles` is used, but this causes some programs to stop working (I don't know what the issue is there exactly, but I would like to avoid modifying the programs).

As far as I understand the function causing the problem initializes some memory and that there is a way to execute code at that time using `__attribute__` e.g. `void __attribute__ ((constructor)) premain()`. This is not the exact function I tried, but I cannot find to other one now. Nevertheless, I was not able to set the stack pointer in them (using inline assembly) before it is used by `__libc_init_array`.

There seems to be a way to set the init priority, but that is only working in C++ e.g. `Some_Class A __attribute__ ((init_priority (2000)));`

I also use the arguments `-pedantic` and `-ffreestanding`.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Isn't this sort of thing usually done in crt0.s? But since it's bare metal you probably need your own startup code.

Comment: I’ve tripped over the same problem. There is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50214840/risc-v-startup-code-for-stack-pointer-initalization#answer-50421199) a **partial** answer to this question.